# JPA ManyToOne returning complete parent entity vs id

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have a springboot application with JPA. The ORM setup is a ManyToOne and I have roughly followed the excellent post here from [Vlad](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) so that I have only setup the @ManyToOne on the child.

My Entities are HealthCheck (Many) which must have a Patient (One). The issue is that when I retrieve a HealthCheck via my Rest controller instead of getting just the id of the patient I get the whole entity.

For my project I probably will get the whole patient with a HealthCheck, but I would like to know how i could get just the HealthCheck with the patient_id instead of the whole patient entity if I so needed to do so.

**HEALTH CHECK**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
public class HealthCheck {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Patient patient;
    //Getters and Setters
```

**PATIENT**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
    private String name;
    // Getters and Setters
```

The HealthCheckServiceImpl uses the derived queries to get one by id, and its this call thats used to get a HealthCheck by the REST controller:

```
@Override
public HealthCheck get(Long id) {
    log.info("Getting a single Health Check");
    return healthCheckRepository.getById(id);
}
```

The result of a call to the REST controller results in something like:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "patient": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jono",
        "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
    },
    "other fields": "some comment",
    "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}
}
```

*Note1 the whole patient entity is returned*

*Note2 that because I have only used the ManyToOne annottaion on the child side I dont get the Jackson recursion issues some others do*

QUESTION: How can I control the returned HealthCheck so that it includes the patient_id not the whole object?

**UPDATE**

The line that calls to the service is :

```
@GetMapping("get/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<HealthCheck> getHealthCheck(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Custom-Header", "foo")
            .body(healthCheckService.get(id));
```

I breakpoint on `healthCheckService.get(id))` but noting on the debugger looks like it contains an entity reference:

[image]

**UPDATE2**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you're returning your entities objects directly from your controller.

> The issue is that when I retrieve a HealthCheck via my Rest controller instead of getting just the id of the patient I get the whole entity.

You can use the DTO Pattern explained [here](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern) as response in your controller.
That, also decouples your domain from your controller layer.
This is a simplified example:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HealthCheckDto {

    private Long id;
    private PatientDto patient;
    private String otherField;

    public HealthCheckDto(HealthCheck healthCheck) {
        this.id = healthCheck.getId();
        this.patient = new PatientDto(healthCheck.getPatient());
        this.otherField = healthCheck.getOtherField();
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PatientDto {

    private Long id;

    public PatientDto(Patient patient) {
        this.id = patient.getId();
    }
}

// In your controller
public ResponseEntity<HealthCheckDto> getHealthCheck(Long id) {
    HealthCheck healthCheck = healthCheckService.getById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new HealthCheckDto(healthCheck));
}
```

Comment: Yes it is my intention to use DTO as I go on, but first I want to understand why the fetch = FetchType.LAZY is not being enforced?

Comment: I think it's fetching the Patient lazy, but when the Controller's response gets deserialized Hibernate loads the complete object because of Jackson's deserialization process (iterate over each property calling its accessor).
Remember that an entity returned by the repository (when FetchType.LAZY), is a proxy, so while you don't call any accessor (getter) on the entity, it remains lazy. But if you "touch" some field, then Hibernate loads it. :)

Comment: Yes, I wondered if that is what was happening. In my IDE (Intellij) can I inspect or evaluate the code and some point to confirm this theory?

Comment: Yes. you can. Just set a breakpoint on the line that calls to the Service, and make your code running. Once the debugger stops on the breakpoint, in the debug tab look at the variables and you'll find the entity one. If can inspect inside of the variable by clicking the arrow on its left. There you can see the specific type of the objects, for example `Patient$HibernateProxy$W2cPgEkQ`.
If you click on the variable's name, then it makes Hibernate to load it.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure my breakpoint is in the right spot. I have added info.

Comment: I just saw the update. Just make a little change for only for this test, extract the service call into a variable, so you have a new line to put the breakpoint in.
`HealthCheck healthCheck = healthCheckService.get(id); //<--The breakpoint here`
`return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Custom-Header", "foo").body(healthCheck);`

Comment: I see HealthCheck$HibernateProxy - but cant seem to get valaues displayed?

Comment: Great! Now you know it's a proxy (remember it's not serializable, then it won't work as return type). Now, try opening the "Evaluate Expression" tool in intelliJ and write into there the next statement `healthCheck.getPatient().get name()` and then press the button "Evaluate". Please, check the type of the Patient inside the healthCheck variable and also check in the standard output console if hibernate has made a query to retrieve the whole Patient.

Comment: But when I click on the variables name - nothing loads? You mean click on healthCheck in debugger? Shouldnt HealthCheck be loaded - but Patient be proxied? (bird = patient in my screen shot)

Comment: Yes,  you're right with that. healthCheck loaded and Patient proxied. Could you try to evaluate the expression `healthCheck.getPatient().get name()`? Another way to trigger it is by manually serializing the healthCheck. Try `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(healthCheck)`

Comment: Evaulate healthCheck.getPatient().getName() works. But stubbornly the patient in healthCheck in the debugger still shows null.

Comment: Yeap, because the proxy is a decorator with null state in all properties.